# Sleep | warning implicit declaration of function `sleep'?

Tags: c, windows, sleep

I am learning C.
In this program
I use sleep function to slowdown a count down.
My text book doesn't  specify a library I should include to use the sleep function.
So I use it without including any special library for it and it works.
But it gives me this warning message in codeblocks.
I tried to include `<windows.h>` but still the same warning message appears.

> warning   D:\Project\C language\trial8\trial8.c|19|warning: implicit
>   declaration of function `sleep'|

And here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int start;

    do
    {
        printf("Please enter the number to start\n");
        printf("the countdown (1 to 100):");
        scanf("%d",&start);
    }
    while(start<1 || start>100);

    do
    {
        printf("T-minus %d\n",start);
        start--;
        sleep(3000); 
    }
    while(start>0);
    printf("Zero!\n Go!\n");
    return(0);
}
```

I want to know what does the warning message mean? How important is it? Is there anything that I should do about it?  Note that the program works anyway.

Comment: So, did you read the man-page of `sleep`? What does it say which **header** you shall include?

Answer (score 17):

The issue is in the libraries (header files):

on *Windows*:

`#include <windows.h>` and `Sleep(1000);` => 1000 milliseconds

on *Linux*:

`#include <unistd.h>` and `sleep(1);` => 1 second

Answer (score 8):

The function `sleep` is not part of C programming language. So, C compiler needs a declaration/prototype of it so that it can get to know about about number of arguments and their data types and return data type of the function. When it doesn't find it, it creates an `Implicit Declaration` of that function.

In Linux, `sleep` has a prototype in `<unistd.h>` and in windows, there is another function `Sleep` which has a prototype in `<windows.h>` or  `<synchapi.h>`.
You can always get away with including header, if you explicitly supply the prototype of the function before using it. It is useful when you need only few functions from a header file.

The prototype of `Sleep` function in C on windows is:

```
VOID WINAPI Sleep(_In_ DWORD dwMilliseconds);
```

Remember, it is always a good practice to supply the prototype of the function being used either by including the appropriate header file or by explicitly writing it. Even, if you don't supply it, compiler will just throw a warning most of the time and it will make an assumption which in most cases will be something that you don't want. It is better to include the header file as API might change in future versions of the Library.

Comment: Portable `sleep`: `unsigned sleep(unsigned x) { time_t t0=time(0); while (difftime(time(0),t0)<x); return 0; }` ;-)

Comment: It's better to use the header, in case the prototype changes in a later version of the API

Comment: @R.: ouch, please clarify that it's a joke, I'm pretty much sure that someone *will* take you seriously (fun fact: in a codebase I work on there are a couple of `clock_t t0 = clock (); while((clock()-t0)/CLOCK_PER_SEC<limit);`. Thanks to busy waiting they are mostly accurate, but they are not exactly a good use of the CPU (and multithreading does make them less accurate).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yes, my portable `sleep` is mostly a joke, but it could presumably be used as a last-resort fallback in places where nothing better is available.

Answer (score 6):

Windows doesn't have the `sleep` function.  Instead, it has `Sleep`, which takes the number of milliseconds to sleep:

```
VOID WINAPI Sleep(
  _In_ DWORD dwMilliseconds
);
```

You'll need to either `#include <windows.h>` or `#include <synchapi.h>`, depending on the version of Windows you're running.  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

## Update in 2022:

As it is stated on the Linux *man* page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) we need to include **unistd.h** and should do fine for all **OS**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

  sleep(1); /* sleep for 1 second*/
  printf("END\n");
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it more cross-platform, try this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
```